# Click not detected after Ajax Callback

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm currently testing on something fairly simple. In my project you can add a listitem via a form and delete it immediately in an updated list. In the beginning of the file I bind the delete click handler:

```
$(".delete").bind("click", this.deleteListitem);
```

I would think that all elements with class "delete" can be removed before or after an Ajax call. So when I add a new listitem with class "delete", I try to click it but it doesn't enter the function. Older items do.

The delete function:

```
PanelRoadtrip.prototype.deleteListitem = function(e)
{
    console.log("click");
    e.preventDefault();

    this.listId = $(event.currentTarget).parent().parent().attr("id");
    this.listItemValue = $(event.currentTarget).parent().text().split(" delete")[0];
    $.ajax({
        type: "delete",
        url: Util.api + "/roadtrip/delete/" + this.tripId + "/" + this.listId + "/" + this.listItemValue,
        dataType: "json"
    });
    //item verwijderen
    $(event.currentTarget).parent().remove();
};
```

Does someone has a simple solution for this problem, searched on Stackoverflow, but found nothing that works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `on()` instead of `bind()` change :

```
$(".delete").bind("click", this.deleteListitem);
```

to

```
$(document).on("click",".delete", this.deleteListitem);
```

(where `document` is a parent element of `.delete` on the DOM at load.

[Docs for `on()` are here](http://api.jquery.com/on/), read the section on Delegated events :

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegated event handler for dynamic created content using `.on()`

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Instead of

```
$(".delete").bind("click", this.deleteListitem);
```

Use

```
$(document).on( "click", ".delete" this.deleteListitem); 
 //Instead of document use a parent container that exists in DOM at any give time.
```

Your newly added element with class `.delete` does not have the event bound by default so this way is to attach the event to the document or a parent container and delegate the events for elements with class `.delete` present now or added later to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Since the element isn't there at DOM ready, you should bind it with `.on()`

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete", this.deleteListitem);
```